# Error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 in fragment by viewPager

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using map in tab(viewPager) and I want to search location in map for this purpose I am using EditText field and array list but I am still getting this error. I couldn't find what's the problem with it. Please anybody suggest me, what should I do?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main    Process: com.example.saroosh.masjidnow, PID: 10465
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 at
    java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255) at
    java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308) at
com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.Tabs.AddMasjid$1.onClick(AddMasjid.java:61) at
    android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)    at
    android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)    at
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)    at
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)    at
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)    at
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)    at
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

My java class is given below.

AddMasjid.java

```
package com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.Tabs;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.R;
import com.google.android.gms.identity.intents.Address;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class AddMasjid extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    MapView gMapView;
    GoogleMap gMap = null;
    Button sButton;
    String location;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_masjid, container, false);
        EditText sLocation = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        location = sLocation.getText().toString();
        sButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.generalId);
        sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                List<android.location.Address> addressList= null;

                if (location != null || !location.equals(""))
                {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLatitude());
                    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Marker"));
                    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
                }

            }
        });

        gMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        gMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        gMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gMap = map;
        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
                LatLng(0, 0), 0));


        if (gMap != null) {
            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                    , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                    , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);


        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gMapView.onResume();

    }

    public void onSearch(View view) throws IOException{

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        gMapView.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        gMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        gMapView.onLowMemory();
    }


}
```

Comment: on what code u get this error?

Comment: At addressList, I couldn't find how can I pass value in it of location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<android.location.Address> addressList= null;
```

and then u

```
android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
```

try Log for checking adding location

```
if (location != null || !location.equals(""))
            {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

becouse this may not give u any record, and with addressList.get(0) u take the position 0 as u know in java positions start from 0,1,2 and if not have the position 0 u will get error BoundOfException

Comment: It would make sense for OP to move the 4 lines after the try-catch to move them inside it (try-catch), because if we don't get the `addressList`, why are we trying to process it?

Comment: @Rodriquez So, how can I pass value in it?

Answer (score 0):

The address list is empty here: `addressList.get(0)`.

Note that not every location has a valid address. Your code must deal with this fact.

Comment: How can I pass value in it with the valid address?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I was passing my location string by `editText` field in `onCreat`method, that is way my `addressList` couldn't find location in list and I got error. When I declare my `editText` in `setOnClickListener` method then my list find the location in it like this:

```
sButton =(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.generalId);
        sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                hideSoftKeyboard(v);
                EditText sLocation = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                location = sLocation.getText().toString();

                List<android.location.Address> addressList= null;

                if (location != null || location.length()>0) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    String locality = address.getLocality();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    double latitude = address.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = address.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
                    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                }

            }
        });
```